# Changing current date on Wordpress Header.php

Tags: php, wordpress

My site uses a Wordpress theme. The theme shows default US date on the header. I would like to change this to Australian time zone. The code that shows US date is below:

```
<div class="current-date">
  <div>
  <?php echo date( 'D, ' . get_option('date_format'), current_time( 'timestamp', 1 ) ); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I change this to Australian time zone date?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the date format for Australian date ?

Comment: @Progi1984 Date has to show in the format "Wed, January 1, 2014"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1` in `current_time( 'timestamp', 1 )` is telling WordPress to show the current time in the GMT time zone, instead of the custom time zone that you set. This is why it's not changing when you change the time zone in the admin area.

Changing the second parameter `$gmt` to `0` instead of `1` will return the local Australian time you set in the General Settings.

So the code would look like:

```
<div class="current-date">
  <div>
  <?php echo date( 'D, ' . get_option('date_format'), current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) ); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get_option('date_format')
```

This code implies that in your wordpress administration panel there should be an option for date format. Please check the admin page that includes settings such as the site name and timezone.

if you are convinced you want to change the hard-code of word-press, replace with the following:

```
<div class="current-date">
 <div>
 <?php echo date( 'D, ' . get_option('date_format'), strtotime('+5 hour') ); ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: I updated that to Sydney local time but still the site shows US time in header.

Comment: Please see screen shots, am I missing something?

Comment: Is the date wrong, or the the formatting of the date wrong?

I have updated my answer with code that will change the date formatting by hardcode.

Comment: From the screenshot, it appears that the timezone of the server hosting your site is incorrect.

Comment: I know in PHP you can change the time zone. I just wanted to know how to do it. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I have updated the answer in a way that will let you manually set the time offset for your site.

Simply adjust +5 until you get to a point that the correct date is shown.  The server your website is on clearly does not have it's clock set correctly, the answer above is dirty but will work once you find out what hour offset you need.

Answer (score 0):

The code `get_option('date_format')` takes the format date in your WP Administration Panel.

You must be confused between "date format" and "timezone"

You can define your date format in the settings general screen (http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen). (Search "Date Format" in the page).

Comment: I want to show Australian time zone date instead on the US time zone date. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen

You can go to Dashboard on the top left corner, then go to settings in the right hand side of the page, then go to general and you can change the time zone there

http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen